# Inline-styled table cell being moved down one pixel

Tags: html, css, html-table, cell

I'm using tables for semantic markup but styling them to resemble lists of multiple lines with icons to the left: http://jsfiddle.net/qs1zsL2s/

However, the inline-styled cells are shown one pixel down from the icons. How do I prevent this, so they begin at the same y-position?

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png" alt="HTML5 logo"></td><td>First cell</td><td>Second cell</td><td>Third cell</td></tr>
        <tr><td><img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png" alt="HTML5 logo"></td><td>First cell</td><td>Second cell</td><td>Third cell</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td {
        display: inline;
        background-color: red;
}
td:first-child {
        display: block;
        float: left;
}
td:last-child {
        display: block;
}
img {
        height: 48px;
}
```

Comment: check this: http://jsfiddle.net/qs1zsL2s/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just updated your fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/qs1zsL2s/2/)

Just add `vertical-align: top` to your td

```
td {
  display: inline;
  background-color: red;
  vertical-align:top;   
}
```

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add in the CSS properties `position:relative` and `top:1px`:

```
td:first-child {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qs1zsL2s/3/)